# gwt "CssResource.style" possible values, how to turn obfuscation ON

Tags: xml, gwt

Is there a documentation of gwt.xml, a list of the setting with all accepted values? In my case i turned css obfuscation off in debug/developer environment.
But for Production environment i want to turn it on. The same i did with "gwt.enableDebugId" it is true in .gwt.xml and false in -production.gwt.xml - this is working fine. The same i want with "CssResource.style".

the only thing i found so far was the value "obf" but it seems that value also produces "human readable classes" see [here for](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml?r=9843) example. i tried this value but the names keep pretty.

the clarification demanded: this turns css obfuscation off:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

but how to turn it on?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: The class names are obfuscated by default. What else do you want to obfuscate?

Comment: But my default profile (developer.gwt.xml) turns it off - in my release profile (release.gwt.xml) i want to turn it ON. With many settings this is working fine: i set defaults in developer and overwrite them in release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That configuration property is defined in [`com/google/gwt/ressources/Ressources.gwt.xml`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.4/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml) that way:

```
<define-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" is-multi-valued="false" />
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="obf" />
```

I.e. the default value is `obf`. I believe `obfuscate` or `obfuscated` would work too (if you find them more readable).

Comment: thx it is working. i tired it without the first line but this is only working if set to pretty (to switch obfuscation off)

Answer (score 9):

For those like me looking for all possible values, here is where to find them (at least in GWT 2.5.0) :

```
com.google.gwt.resources.rg.CssObfuscationStyle
```

---

```
pretty -->           VERBOSE (true, false, true, true),
stable -->           STABLE_FULL_CLASSNAME (true, true, true, true),
stable-shorttype --> STABLE_SHORT_CLASSNAME (true, true, true, false),
stable-notype -->    STABLE_NO_CLASSNAME (true, true, false, false),
[default] -->        OBFUSCATED (false, false, false, false);
```

boolean values stands for :

```
isPretty, isStable, showClassName, showPackageName
```

The only unclear value is isStable which will if set to `false` prefix your pretty name with the obfuscated name and a "-".

Comment: `isStable` will guarantee that the class names won't change between builds. But while guaranteeing stability, GWT can't guarantee that the class names will be free of conflicts.