# gwt remove obfuscation with ui:binder

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I understand that I can use

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

to get my class names to show from css in my `resources` folder.
However, I have been unable to do so with inlined style in `ui.binder`.
For example, I can't get the css class names below to appear with the non-obfuscated class name.

```
<ui:style field="style">
    .alignRight {float:right};
    .displayNone {display:none};
    .ack { background-color: grey; border: solid 2pk darkgray; float: right;}
    .fullwidth { left: 0px; right: 0px;}
</ui:style>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gwt “CssResource.style” possible values, how to turn obfuscation ON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772627/gwt-cssresource-style-possible-values-how-to-turn-obfuscation-on)

Comment: I've looked around, the difference here is that it's declared in a `ui.xml` file for one of my widgets. I still want to turn it OFF. its that my css file isnt explicitely declared anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want those classes to be available always with its name and not being modified by the gwt compiler, declare them as external

```
<ui:style field="style">
   @external .alignRight, .displayNone, .ack, .fullwidth;
   .alignRight {float:right};
   .displayNone {display:none};
   .ack { background-color: grey; border: solid 2pk darkgray; float: right;}
   .fullwidth { left: 0px; right: 0px;}
</ui:style>
```